# Why can image be imported with require("../images/restaurants/sea.jpeg"), but not with require(this.props.image)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, require

Within my create-react-app project, I'm building a react component with an image in it. 
I want to pass the exact image location through as component-property (or -state).
Within my component, I'm using require, like this:

```
<Image
      height={"100px"}
      borderRadius={8}
      src={require(this.props.image)}
      alt="logo"
    />
```

Which gives this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../images/restaurants/sea.jpeg'

webpackEmptyContext
src/components sync:2
```

However, when I hardcode the exact value I'm passing through the property into require it does work!

```
<Image
      height={"100px"}
      borderRadius={8}
      src={require("../images/restaurants/sea.jpeg")}
      alt="logo"
    />
```

Why does this work so counter-intuitively? And what is the best workaround?

Comment: If you really need to `require` your image as a base64 uri it's usually done outside the component definition. Then you pass the uri string as a prop. There's really no reason to `require` in the `render` function. Eslint will usually warn you about this as what you are doing is not "typical" https://eslint.org/docs/rules/global-require

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack needs to know about the file at the time of bundling - otherwise it won't include it (it's trying to keep the size of your bundle down).

If you pass the file path as a prop it doesn't know about it at bundle time - it only knows about it at runtime.

The suggested solution of passing the base64 encoded image is a good one - alternatively you could pass in a url to a publicly hosted image?

Answer (score 1):

There is way you can achieve what you want to if the set of images is fixed and known at the compile time. For that you have to place all such images in one folder and using `webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin` you can create a webpack context for that folder. Then whenever you have to require that image you have to use this sytax `require("images/restaurants/" + this.props.image)` assuming the webpack context is created for `images/restaurants` and this.props.image contains only the file name.